# How to include a string vector or sys.date() intro the read_excel path Rstudio?

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to open an xlsx file but the file name contains the date of the day so, I want to add this sys.date into the path of read_excel, something like this:

```
mydate<-sys.date()
DAT <- read_excel(paste("C:/Users/Desktop/",mydate,".xlsx"),  sheet = "2")
```

I use something similar to export files but with read_excel is not working. 
I really appreciate any answer.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: In principle your solutiuon should work, but you need to make sure that the date format returned by the function you use to get the date (I think you mean `Sys.Date()` - `lubridate::today()` is another option) matches the function used in the file path.  Also, will your file path always include TODAY'S date, or will you need to allow for the possibility of other dates?

Comment: In addition, you might want `paste0` or use `sep = ""` to prevent spaces in your file path.